# Do "Arrow" and "The Flash" share sets?

Tags: production, film-location, the-flash, arrow, arrowverse

Watching a recent episode of ***Arrow*** (Season 4 Episode 15 "Taken"), I get a feeling that Oliver's Star City mayoral race campaign headquarters looks incredibly identical to Central City's Police Department (Earth 1, as seen in basically every episode). The windows and door and everything.

Considering the cross overs and everything, do they share sets or filming crews too? Or is the similarity just superficial?

Comment: Also the coffee shops are awfully similar, pretty sure they just have different signage

Comment: I've also noticed that the corridors of the Waverider ship in Legends of Tomorrow seem awfully similar to STAR Labs.

Comment: Not Arrow and The Flash, but Damien Darhk (Arrow) and 1970s Vandal Savage (Legends of Tomorrow) have the same house, which looks awfully close to the Queen family house (not sure if they are the same though).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They do to an extent.

They are both filmed in [Vancouver](https://www.comicbookmovie.com/the_flash/the-cws-the-flash-set-to-begin-filming-in-vancouver-in-march-a93953) and share some of the same sets and production teams. This is apparent with places like the coffee shop:

**Arrow**:

[image: Grind and Jolt Café form the Arrow TV show]

**The Flash**:

[image: CC Jitters café from The Flash TV show]

But Oliver Queen's mayoral headquarters and Flash's CCPD building ([taken from YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugqPiCKEYb0)) are not the same (notice the windows):

[image: Oliver Queen's mayoral headquarters] [image: CCPD open space with two characters talking to each other]

Having a quick look through the IMDb crew lists for [*The Flash*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3107288/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ql_dt_1) and [*The Arrow*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193021/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ql_1), there's some definite overlaps in the teams as well.

For example, *Arrow*'s cinematography:

> Gordon Verheul   ... (56 episodes, 2012-2016)
>   ***Glen Winter***   ...
>   (32 episodes, 2012-2014)
>   Corey Robson   ... (22 episodes,
>   2014-2016)
>   ***C. Kim Miles***   ... (6 episodes, 2013-2014)
>   Gregory
>   Middleton   ... (1 episode, 2013)
>   Shamus Whiting-Hewlett   ... (1
>   episode, 2016)

*The Flash*'s cinematography:

> ***C. Kim Miles***   ... (23 episodes, 2014-2016)
>   Jeffrey C. Mygatt  ... (11 episodes, 2014-2015)
>   Stewart Whelan   ... (8 episodes,
>   2015-2016)
>   ***Glen Winter***   ... (1 episode, 2014)

Likewise for film editing in *Arrow*:

> Kristin Windell   ... (38 episodes, 2012-2014)
>   Andi Armaganian  ... (35 episodes, 2012-2014)
>   ***Paul Karasick***   ... (15 episodes,
>   2012-2014)
>   Jessie Murray   ... (4 episodes, 2015)
>   Thomas
>   Wallerstein   ... (3 episodes, 2015)
>   Carol Stutz   ... (2 episodes,
>   2015-2016)

And for *The Flash*:

> Chris Conlee   ... (10 episodes, 2015-2016)
>   Nathan Draper   ... (7
>   episodes, 2014-2015)
>   Harry Jierjian   ... (7 episodes, 2014-2015)
>   ***Paul Karasick***   ... (7 episodes, 2014-2015)
>   Dan Wilken   ... (6
>   episodes, 2015-2016)

So definitely not a *complete* overlap with identical teams, but certainly shared resources. Looking at the timelines involved, it appears that as *The Flash* became more established, it got more of its own "dedicated" crew.

Comment: @cde: I'll have to put it on the to do list. I'm struggling to find pictures online showing the similarity and I can't think off the top of my head what episodes to start with online to find them.

Comment: Ah, they aren't the same set. The windows of the Campaign office and CCPD are completely different. Jitters and G&J Cafe are the same though. Accepted :D

Comment: Just found http://imgur.com/a/HDYTT and https://www.reddit.com/r/arrow/comments/2kqswf/either_the_arrowflash_universe_has_cookiecutter/ The 100 and Arrow shared props too? Lol

Comment: @cde: I'm not sure I agreed with the different actually. It's *identical* otherwise. I wonder if they covered up windows, or did something else silly to change this. Everything else is just so similar that it's throwing me!

Comment: They would have had to put significant work in to change the window and wall sizing. And the door/glass wall of Captain Singh office and Oliver's office are slightly different too.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Andrew Martin's answer:
The set used for the appartment of John Diggle (Arrow) is the same as that of Patty Spivot (Flash)
**Diggle's appartment**
[image: Diggle]
**Patty's appartment**
[image: Patty]

Comment: Really nice spot!